# OpenERP - onchange method for fields in different page of view?

Tags: python, xml, view, odoo, onchange

It seems onchange method only works on current visible fields. If I use it to fill other fields that are in other pages of the view, it does not do anything. For example I have view with many pages. Mainly all information needs to be filled in first page, so most fields are filled correctly. But there is one field I need to fill in other page, when I choose `partner_id` in another page. For example in view like this:

```
...
<page string="page1">
  <field name=partner_id on_change="onchange_partner(partner_id)"
  <field name="field1"/>
  <field name="field2"/>

</page>
<page string="page2">
   <field name="field3"/>
</page>
...
```

`field1` and `field2` will be filled. But how to fill field3 or is it impossible, because system do not save it into database using onchange method?

My onchange method looks something like this:

```
def onchange_partner(self, cr, uid, ids, partner_id, context=None):
  res = {}
  if partner_id:
    obj = self.pool.get('res.partner').browse(cr, uid, partner_id)
    res['field1'] = obj.field1
    res['field2'] = obj.field2
    res['field3'] = obj.field3 # this value isn't being filled
  return {'value': res}
```

So how could I fill `field3`?

Comment: check your field type of 'field3' and obj.field3 r both same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not like that. It will definitely change the value. you might not be getting value in field3 because the record you are fetching will not have value of field3. and answer to your question is **IT WORKS. Try this,**

```
def onchange_partner(self, cr, uid, ids, partner_id, context=None):
    res = {}
    if partner_id:
        obj = self.pool.get('res.partner').browse(cr, uid, partner_id)
        res['field1'] = obj.field1
        res['field2'] = obj.field2
        res['field3'] = 'Hello' # this field type must be char or if not then give 
        #value accordingly, its just to prove you that values are filled on onchange.
    return {'value': res}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: You are right. It works. The problem was with field3. When demo partner was created that field didn't have domain slapped on it. When I tested it, then that field had domain, but that field didn't satisfy domain and couldn't be selected. But now it is fixed. Thanks.